# Redirect stdout to a file only for a specific thread

Tags: python, stdout

I have couple of processes with its own threads all writing to `stdout` and I am OK with it. Now, I have to add another thread, which is going to dump a lot of garbage to stdout and I don't want this.

Is there any way I can redirect the `stdout` for a single thread to a file?

**Update**

As mentioned by [owobeid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643661/owobeid), I tried this... I am redirecting `stderr` to a file...

```
def startServer():
    fd = os.open("foo.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT )
    fd2 = 2
    os.dup2(fd, fd2)

    # rest of the code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=startServer).start()
    raise Exception("My Exception")
```

Issue: `stderr` for the whole app is redirected. The Exception message also gets redirected into the file, even though it is outside the thread.

Comment: Accepted answer is not correct since file descriptors are shared by threads, see umichscoots's answer. I have tested it and it works great.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use [dup2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_dup2.htm) to redirect the output to a file of your choice. Set fd to your file descriptor and fd2 to 1 (stdout).

Note: Do this inside the spawned thread, not in the main thread.

Comment: I can duplicate stdout, what difference does this make?

Comment: Read [this](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:dup2) to get a better picture.

Comment: Ok, I think I know the problem. You are using Python threads which are all run in the same interpreter and therefore share the same file descriptor table. Try using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead.

Comment: Because of the way I am using the objects, I cannot use multiprocessing, it will throw `PicklingError`. So, I will need a mechanism to do this within threads.

Comment: The approved answer is not valid. See answer provided by @umichscoots

Answer (score 12):

I stumbled across this post while searching for a way to do exactly this.  I wanted to make an interactive Python console that uses ajax to proxy requests to a server, and return all output for only the thread executing.  I ended up figuring it out and wanted to share my solution.

There's a class that comes with the `werkzeug` python library called `local.LocalProxy` that can make a module-level function behave like a property.  For example, this will make `sys.stdout` behave exactly as normal, but it will be proxied through the `LocalProxy` class.

```
import sys
import werkzeug
sys.stdout = werkzeug.local.LocalProxy(lambda: sys.stdout)
```

Expanding on this, I then wrote a function in place of the `lambda` above to return a `StringIO` object if it's a different thread:

```
import threading
import sys
import cStringIO
import werkzeug

thread_proxies = {}
def redirect():
    ident = threading.currentThread().ident
    thread_proxies[ident] = cStringIO.StringIO()
    return thread_proxies[ident]

def proxy():
    ident = threading.currentThread().ident
    return thread_proxies.get(ident, sys.stdout)

sys.stdout = werkzeug.local.LocalProxy(proxy)
```

And then in any thread I want redirected, I can just call:

```
string_io = redirect()
```

And all of the output that would go to `sys.stdout` is instead now written to the `StringIO` object.

---

But wait! I need to capture `sys.stdout`, `sys.__stdout__`, `sys.stderr`, and `sys.__stderr__`, so I wrote this library, which I called `stdout_helpers` in my codebase:

```
import threading
import sys
import cStringIO
from werkzeug import local

# Save all of the objects for use later.
orig___stdout__ = sys.__stdout__
orig___stderr__ = sys.__stderr__
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
orig_stderr = sys.stderr
thread_proxies = {}


def redirect():
    """
    Enables the redirect for the current thread's output to a single cStringIO
    object and returns the object.

    :return: The StringIO object.
    :rtype: ``cStringIO.StringIO``
    """
    # Get the current thread's identity.
    ident = threading.currentThread().ident

    # Enable the redirect and return the cStringIO object.
    thread_proxies[ident] = cStringIO.StringIO()
    return thread_proxies[ident]


def stop_redirect():
    """
    Enables the redirect for the current thread's output to a single cStringIO
    object and returns the object.

    :return: The final string value.
    :rtype: ``str``
    """
    # Get the current thread's identity.
    ident = threading.currentThread().ident

    # Only act on proxied threads.
    if ident not in thread_proxies:
        return

    # Read the value, close/remove the buffer, and return the value.
    retval = thread_proxies[ident].getvalue()
    thread_proxies[ident].close()
    del thread_proxies[ident]
    return retval


def _get_stream(original):
    """
    Returns the inner function for use in the LocalProxy object.

    :param original: The stream to be returned if thread is not proxied.
    :type original: ``file``
    :return: The inner function for use in the LocalProxy object.
    :rtype: ``function``
    """
    def proxy():
        """
        Returns the original stream if the current thread is not proxied,
        otherwise we return the proxied item.

        :return: The stream object for the current thread.
        :rtype: ``file``
        """
        # Get the current thread's identity.
        ident = threading.currentThread().ident

        # Return the proxy, otherwise return the original.
        return thread_proxies.get(ident, original)

    # Return the inner function.
    return proxy


def enable_proxy():
    """
    Overwrites __stdout__, __stderr__, stdout, and stderr with the proxied
    objects.
    """
    sys.__stdout__ = local.LocalProxy(_get_stream(sys.__stdout__))
    sys.__stderr__ = local.LocalProxy(_get_stream(sys.__stderr__))
    sys.stdout = local.LocalProxy(_get_stream(sys.stdout))
    sys.stderr = local.LocalProxy(_get_stream(sys.stderr))


def disable_proxy():
    """
    Overwrites __stdout__, __stderr__, stdout, and stderr with the original
    objects.
    """
    sys.__stdout__ = orig___stdout__
    sys.__stderr__ = orig___stderr__
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout
    sys.stderr = orig_stderr
```

And now at the start of my app I call:

```
stdout_helpers.enable_proxy()
```

And in any thread I now call:

```
string_io = stdout_helpers.redirect()
```

Comment: This is really clever. Thanks. There's one problem with it though, no? It's not thread-safe. I used this idea but added an RLock to protect the thread_proxies dict and the setting of the sys.*. Thoughts, @umichscoots?

Comment: `stdout_helpers.enable_proxy()` should only ever be called once, it is used to set up the proxy objects and it should be called at the start of an app.  I didn't bother to make it synchronous, because if it's called more than once it will produce unreliable results.  Since everything referencing a single key in `thread_proxies` would be in one thread, the built in dictionary types are safe enough.

Comment: Thanks! I really like this solution, but did not want to add Werkzeug as a dependency to my project, so, as it is BSD licensed, I just extracted the LocalProxy class and made it a standalone lib: https://gitlab.com/yquemener/stdout-redirects

Answer (score 4):

This answer allow redirecting to specific file, but also to have multiple outputs (sys.stdout + file), and also to redirect main thread logs to each thread filelog (which was very useful in my case).

First of all, let's define a class for new redirection :

```
class SysRedirect(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout                  # To continue writing to terminal
        self.log={}                                 # A dictionary of file pointers for file logging

    def register(self,filename):                    # To start redirecting to filename
        ident = threading.currentThread().ident     # Get thread ident (thanks @michscoots)
        if ident in self.log:                       # If already in dictionary :
            self.log[ident].close()                 # Closing current file pointer
        self.log[ident] = open(filename, "a")       # Creating a new file pointed associated with thread id

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)                # Write in terminal (comment this line to remove terminal logging)
        ident = threading.currentThread().ident     # Get Thread id
        if ident in self.log:                       # Check if file pointer exists
            self.log[ident].write(message)          # write in file
        else:                                       # if no file pointer 
            for ident in self.log:                  # write in all thread (this can be replaced by a Write in terminal)
                 self.log[ident].write(message)  
     def flush(self):
            #this flush method is needed for python 3 compatibility.
            #this handles the flush command by doing nothing.
            #you might want to specify some extra behavior here.
            pass
```

Then, I only need to initialise in my main thread

```
sys.stdout=SysRedirect()
```

Then in each thread, I only have to register and specifying a filename

```
sys.stdout.register('threadX.log')
```

And in main Thread, I can redirect for example to :

```
sys.stdout.register('mainthread.log')
```

But in my case I prefer not to register the main Thread so all std in main thread is written in all others logs

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect stdout for a single thread, but you can write to a different fd by e.g. opening a file and calling `write()` on it from that thread.  stdout and stderr map to specific fds that are part of the fd table for the whole process, so messing with stdout/stderr in any one thread messes with all of them.

So in this situation you cannot simply mess with stdout underneath a single thread so that you could e.g. still call vanilla 'print'. The distinction made in the prior answer b/w the spawned thread and main thread is not relevant. You need your thread of choice to actually print to a separate fd:

```
with open('blah', 'w') as f:
    f.write('bla blah\n')
```

I know that doesn't give you what you want, but for later readers coming along this is important to know.

Something that could help conceptually is to understand what the print command does underneath the hood.  Essentially it does the same sort of thing as `fd.write()` (modulo the formatting niceties), but it uses stdout as the file handle specifically. You can do this ourself using `sys.stdout.write()`.