# Capture debug output from Python smtplib

Tags: python, error-handling, smtplib

How do I capture the debug output from the Python smtplib library?

Here is my test program:

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP("mx10.comcast.com")
s.set_debuglevel(1)
s.sendmail("no-such-sender@comcast.com",["no-such-receiver@comcast.com"],"""
from: no-such-sender@comcast.com
to: no-such-receiver@comcast.com
subject: no such message

This message won't be delivered to anybody.
""")
```

Here is the output:

```
send: 'ehlo dance.local\r\n'
reply: '250-mx10.comcast.com says EHLO to 129.6.220.67:57015\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 40000000\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250 XXXXXXXA\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: mx10.comcast.com says EHLO to 129.6.220.67:57015
SIZE 40000000
PIPELINING
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8BITMIME
XXXXXXXA
send: 'mail FROM:<no-such-sender@comcast.com> size=137\r\n'
reply: '250 2.0.0 MAIL FROM accepted\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 MAIL FROM accepted
send: 'rcpt TO:<no-such-receiver@comcast.com>\r\n'
reply: '550 5.1.1 Recipient address rejected: {Gateway}\r\n'
reply: retcode (550); Msg: 5.1.1 Recipient address rejected: {Gateway}
send: 'rset\r\n'
reply: '250 2.0.0 RSET OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 RSET OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/simsong/x.py", line 11, in <module>
    """)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 742, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'no-such-receiver@comcast.com': (550, '5.1.1 Recipient address rejected: {Gateway}')}
```

I want the output in a variable, `output`.  Specifically, I want all of the lines that begin with `send:` and `reply:`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done by redirecting stderr to a file:

```
import tempfile, smtplib, os, sys

# Find an available file descriptor                                                                                              
t = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
available_fd = t.fileno()
t.close()

# now make a copy of stderr                                                                                                      
os.dup2(2,available_fd)

# Now create a new tempfile and make Python's stderr go to that file                                                             
t = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
os.dup2(t.fileno(),2)

# Now run the task that logs to stderr                                                                                           
s = smtplib.SMTP("mx10.comcast.com")
s.set_debuglevel(1)
s.sendmail("no-such-sender@comcast.com",["no-such-receiver@comcast.com"],"""                                                     
from: no-such-sender@comcast.com                                                                                                 
to: no-such-receiver@comcast.com                                                                                                 
subject: no such message                                                                                                         

This message won't be delivered to anybody.                                                                                      
""")

# Grab the stderr from the temp file                                                                                             
sys.stderr.flush()
t.flush()
t.seek(0)
stderr_output = t.read()
t.close()

# Put back stderr                                                                                                                
os.dup2(available_fd,2)
os.close(available_fd)


# Finally, demonstrate that we have the output:                                                                                  
print("STDERR:")
count = 0
for line in stderr_output.decode('utf-8').split("\n"):
    count += 1
    print("{:3} {}".format(count,line))
```

Answer (score 1):

Study the error:

```
a = None
try:
    s.sendmail("no-such-sender@comcast.com"   ["no-suchreceiver@comcast.com"],"""
    from: no-such-sender@comcast.com
    to: no-such-receiver@comcast.com
    subject: no such message

    This message won't be delivered to anybody.
    """)
except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused as e:
    a = e
```

Now you can look at how to extract it:

```
a.args
```

> ({'no-such-receiver@comcast.com': (550,
>      b'5.1.1 Recipient address rejected: {Gateway}')},)

```
a.args[0]['no-such-receiver@comcast.com'][1]
```

> b'5.1.1 Recipient address rejected: {Gateway}'

And here is your message!

So to extract it:

```
message = None
try:
    s.sendmail("...")

except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
    message = e.args[0]['no-such-receiver@comcast.com'][1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the Python Exception, I want the SMTP transcript. All of the lines that begin `send:` and `reply:`

Answer (score 0):

To others who wants to make this work with multithreading, we can combine the answers here - [Redirect stdout to a file only for a specific thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890997/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-only-for-a-specific-thread#comment114625387_43667367) and https://gitlab.com/yquemener/stdout-redirects

#### main.py

```
import stdout_redirects
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import itertools_len as itertools
import tqdm
import time

pbar = None

def multithread_capture_output(string_input_1, string_input_2):
    global pbar
    time.sleep(1)
    # In a thread where you want to redirect the output do:
    string_io = stdout_redirects.redirect()
    print(string_input_1 + " " + string_input_2)
    string_io.seek(0)
    string_output = string_io.read()
    stdout_redirects.stop_redirect()
    pbar.update(1)
    return string_output

def main():
    global pbar
    
    # In Main Thread
    list_of_input1 = [str(i).zfill(6) for i in range(0, 10)]
    list_of_input2 = ["sample_string"]
    
    
    stdout_redirects.enable_proxy()
    multithreading_input = itertools.product(list_of_input1, list_of_input2)
    pool = ThreadPool(1)
    
    pbar = tqdm.tqdm(total=len(list_of_input1)*len(list_of_input2))
    list_of_output = pool.starmap(multithread_capture_output, multithreading_input)
    pool.close()
    pool.join() 
    pbar.close()
    
    print("# Output of all Threads #")
    for output in list_of_output:
        print(output)
    
    
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### stdout_redirects.py

```
# copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667367/1193986
#
# (c) umichscoots 2017
# License unsepcified. Assumed to be CC-by-sa as is StackOverflow's policy
#
# The class LocalProxy is taken from the werkzeug project
# https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pallets/werkzeug/ef545f0d0bf28cbad02066b4cb7471bea50a93ee/src/werkzeug/local.py
# It is licensed under the BSD-3-Clause License
#
# I guess that means the result is CC-by-SA


import threading
import sys
from io import StringIO

from typing import Any
from typing import Optional
from typing import Union

# Save all of the objects for use later.
orig___stdout__ = sys.__stdout__
orig___stderr__ = sys.__stderr__
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
orig_stderr = sys.stderr
thread_proxies = {}


class LocalProxy:
    """Acts as a proxy for a werkzeug local.  Forwards all operations to
    a proxied object.  The only operations not supported for forwarding
    are right handed operands and any kind of assignment.
    Example usage::
        from werkzeug.local import Local
        l = Local()
        # these are proxies
        request = l('request')
        user = l('user')
        from werkzeug.local import LocalStack
        _response_local = LocalStack()
        # this is a proxy
        response = _response_local()
    Whenever something is bound to l.user / l.request the proxy objects
    will forward all operations.  If no object is bound a :exc:`RuntimeError`
    will be raised.
    To create proxies to :class:`Local` or :class:`LocalStack` objects,
    call the object as shown above.  If you want to have a proxy to an
    object looked up by a function, you can (as of Werkzeug 0.6.1) pass
    a function to the :class:`LocalProxy` constructor::
        session = LocalProxy(lambda: get_current_request().session)
    .. versionchanged:: 0.6.1
       The class can be instantiated with a callable as well now.
    """

    __slots__ = ("__local", "__dict__", "__name__", "__wrapped__")

    def __init__(
        self, local: Union[Any, "LocalProxy", "LocalStack"], name: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:
        object.__setattr__(self, "_LocalProxy__local", local)
        object.__setattr__(self, "__name__", name)
        if callable(local) and not hasattr(local, "__release_local__"):
            # "local" is a callable that is not an instance of Local or
            # LocalManager: mark it as a wrapped function.
            object.__setattr__(self, "__wrapped__", local)

    def _get_current_object(self,) -> object:
        """Return the current object.  This is useful if you want the real
        object behind the proxy at a time for performance reasons or because
        you want to pass the object into a different context.
        """
        if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
            return self.__local()
        try:
            return getattr(self.__local, self.__name__)
        except AttributeError:
            raise RuntimeError(f"no object bound to {self.__name__}")

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        try:
            return self._get_current_object().__dict__
        except RuntimeError:
            raise AttributeError("__dict__")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        try:
            obj = self._get_current_object()
        except RuntimeError:
            return f"<{type(self).__name__} unbound>"
        return repr(obj)

    def __bool__(self) -> bool:
        try:
            return bool(self._get_current_object())
        except RuntimeError:
            return False

    def __dir__(self):
        try:
            return dir(self._get_current_object())
        except RuntimeError:
            return []

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any:
        if name == "__members__":
            return dir(self._get_current_object())
        return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)

    def __setitem__(self, key: Any, value: Any) -> None:
        self._get_current_object()[key] = value  # type: ignore

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._get_current_object()[key]

    __setattr__ = lambda x, n, v: setattr(x._get_current_object(), n, v)  # type: ignore
    __delattr__ = lambda x, n: delattr(x._get_current_object(), n)  # type: ignore
    __str__ = lambda x: str(x._get_current_object())  # type: ignore
    __lt__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() < o
    __le__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() <= o
    __eq__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() == o  # type: ignore
    __ne__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() != o  # type: ignore
    __gt__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() > o
    __ge__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() >= o
    __hash__ = lambda x: hash(x._get_current_object())  # type: ignore
    __call__ = lambda x, *a, **kw: x._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
    __len__ = lambda x: len(x._get_current_object())
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
    __iter__ = lambda x: iter(x._get_current_object())
    __contains__ = lambda x, i: i in x._get_current_object()
    __add__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() + o
    __sub__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() - o
    __mul__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() * o
    __floordiv__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() // o
    __mod__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() % o
    __divmod__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object().__divmod__(o)
    __pow__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() ** o
    __lshift__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() << o
    __rshift__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() >> o
    __and__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() & o
    __xor__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() ^ o
    __or__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object() | o
    __div__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object().__div__(o)
    __truediv__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object().__truediv__(o)
    __neg__ = lambda x: -(x._get_current_object())
    __pos__ = lambda x: +(x._get_current_object())
    __abs__ = lambda x: abs(x._get_current_object())
    __invert__ = lambda x: ~(x._get_current_object())
    __complex__ = lambda x: complex(x._get_current_object())
    __int__ = lambda x: int(x._get_current_object())
    __long__ = lambda x: long(x._get_current_object())  # type: ignore # noqa
    __float__ = lambda x: float(x._get_current_object())
    __oct__ = lambda x: oct(x._get_current_object())
    __hex__ = lambda x: hex(x._get_current_object())
    __index__ = lambda x: x._get_current_object().__index__()
    __coerce__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object().__coerce__(x, o)
    __enter__ = lambda x: x._get_current_object().__enter__()
    __exit__ = lambda x, *a, **kw: x._get_current_object().__exit__(*a, **kw)
    __radd__ = lambda x, o: o + x._get_current_object()
    __rsub__ = lambda x, o: o - x._get_current_object()
    __rmul__ = lambda x, o: o * x._get_current_object()
    __rdiv__ = lambda x, o: o / x._get_current_object()
    __rtruediv__ = __rdiv__
    __rfloordiv__ = lambda x, o: o // x._get_current_object()
    __rmod__ = lambda x, o: o % x._get_current_object()
    __rdivmod__ = lambda x, o: x._get_current_object().__rdivmod__(o)
    __copy__ = lambda x: copy.copy(x._get_current_object())
    __deepcopy__ = lambda x, memo: copy.deepcopy(x._get_current_object(), memo)


def redirect():
    """
    Enables the redirect for the current thread's output to a single cStringIO
    object and returns the object.

    :return: The StringIO object.
    :rtype: ``cStringIO.StringIO``
    """
    # Get the current thread's identity.
    ident = threading.currentThread().ident

    # Enable the redirect and return the cStringIO object.
    thread_proxies[ident] = StringIO()
    return thread_proxies[ident]


def stop_redirect():
    """
    Enables the redirect for the current thread's output to a single cStringIO
    object and returns the object.

    :return: The final string value.
    :rtype: ``str``
    """
    # Get the current thread's identity.
    ident = threading.currentThread().ident

    # Only act on proxied threads.
    if ident not in thread_proxies:
        return

    # Read the value, close/remove the buffer, and return the value.
    retval = thread_proxies[ident].getvalue()
    thread_proxies[ident].close()
    del thread_proxies[ident]
    return retval


def _get_stream(original):
    """
    Returns the inner function for use in the LocalProxy object.

    :param original: The stream to be returned if thread is not proxied.
    :type original: ``file``
    :return: The inner function for use in the LocalProxy object.
    :rtype: ``function``
    """
    def proxy():
        """
        Returns the original stream if the current thread is not proxied,
        otherwise we return the proxied item.

        :return: The stream object for the current thread.
        :rtype: ``file``
        """
        # Get the current thread's identity.
        ident = threading.currentThread().ident

        # Return the proxy, otherwise return the original.
        return thread_proxies.get(ident, original)

    # Return the inner function.
    return proxy


def enable_proxy():
    """
    Overwrites __stdout__, __stderr__, stdout, and stderr with the proxied
    objects.
    """
    sys.__stdout__ = LocalProxy(_get_stream(sys.__stdout__))
    sys.__stderr__ = LocalProxy(_get_stream(sys.__stderr__))
    sys.stdout = LocalProxy(_get_stream(sys.stdout))
    sys.stderr = LocalProxy(_get_stream(sys.stderr))


def disable_proxy():
    """
    Overwrites __stdout__, __stderr__, stdout, and stderr with the original
    objects.
    """
    sys.__stdout__ = orig___stdout__
    sys.__stderr__ = orig___stderr__
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout
    sys.stderr = orig_stderr
```