# Python smtplib hangs when sendmessage() is called

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I'm trying to send a message from a gmail account using smtplib. I've been messing with it in the shell, and everything works fine until I call sendmail(), when it just freezes until I close the terminal. No errors, just freezing. My commands look like this:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
>>> connection.ehlo()
>>> connection.starttls()
>>> connection.login("gmail_id", "gmail_pwd")
>>> connection.sendmail("addr_from", "addr_to", "message")
```

Has anybody had this problem? I've tried pinging smtp.gmail.com and using telnet smtp.gmail.com 587, and they both connect.

Comment: Enable tracking/debugging smtp session as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294251/capture-debug-output-from-python-smtplib

Comment: If `"message"` is really what you are trying to send, that's the problem right there. The argument should be a well-formed RFC5322 message.

Answer (score 1):

## Debugging SMTP session in python's smtplib

Use `connection.set_debuglevel(1)` to enable tracking/debugging SMTP session.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.set_debuglevel

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question, though it might be useful in getting the OP to post actually useful diagnostics. Linking to Python 2 documentation in 2020 is rather disingenuous.

Comment: @tripleee IMHO Solving OP problem is impossible without much better diagnostic.  I am sick a tired by "long diagnostic exchanges in comments".

Comment: Amen, brother. The solution to that is to vote to close as unclear, and take care to vote to reopen once the OP provides enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just now, I had tried to login to my gmail account using python3.7's `smtplib` and was getting:

`smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials')`

I went to my gmail inbox using a browser, saw that I received a security alert email with the message

> Less secure app blocked: Google blocked the app you were trying to use
>   because it doesn't meet our security standards.Some apps and devices
>   use less secure sign-in technology, which makes your account more
>   vulnerable. You can turn off access for these apps, which we
>   recommend, or turn on access if you want to use them despite the
>   risks. Google will automatically turn this setting OFF if it's not
>   being used.

After I followed the instructions in the aforementioned email and enabled less secure apps access on my gmail account, I tried `sendmail` still using the initial SMTP connection, but it just hung with no output.

I then proceeded to quit the initial SMTP connection and created a new one (post less secure apps enabled) like below and it worked!

```
conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```