# Send email from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use the page https://outlook.elbbusinessmail.com/ to send emails from my corporate account and I'm a bit stuck because I can't send the email. The code I am using is:

```
import smtplib
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='outlook.elbbusinessmail.com', port=443)
    
    #Next, log in to the server
    server.login("myaccount@company.com", "Password")
    
    #Send the mail
    msg = "Hello!" # The /n separates the message from the headers
    server.sendmail("myaccount@company.com", "target@company.com", msg)
```

436/5000
I think the problem is with the server. I also have configured on my mobile the account from which I send and receive emails and the server that appears to me is exchange.mycompany.com, the port is 443 and it is configured to accept all SSL / TLS certificates.

I have tried almost everything, changing the server to the same one that appears on my mobile "exchange.mycompany.com" with port 443 and nothing.

Any ideas ?

Thank you very much

Comment: get the debug output and check. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294251/capture-debug-output-from-python-smtplib).

Comment: Do try [`exchangelib`](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/) makes it much simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how i did it

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

 requirements = {'Baggage Related': [(['pnr'], r"(\d[\- ]?){10}"), (['bag color', 'color'],)], 'Refund': [(['pnr'] ,r"(\d[\- ]?){10}"), (['train name', 'train'],), (['origin', 'from'],), (['destination', 'to'],), (['mobile no','mobile number','mobile','phone'],r"[+]?(\d[\- ]?){10,13}"), (['card no', 'card number', 'card'], r"(\d[\- ]?)+"), (['booking id', 'transaction id', 'referance id', 'referance no'],), (['refund amount', 'amount'],)], 'Special Assistance': [ (['pnr'], r"(\d[\- ]?){10}"), (['destination', 'to'],), (['origin', 'from'],)]}


def send_mail(mail, ticket):
 sender = 'support@bookticket.com'
 receivers = [mail]

 msg = EmailMessage()
 msg.set_content(generate_mail(ticket))

 msg['Subject'] = "RE: " + ticket['response_list'][0]['content']['subject']


 server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
 server.ehlo()
 server.starttls()
 server.ehlo()
 server.login("USERNAME@gmail.com", "PASSWORD")
 server.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
 server.quit()
```

Sorry for the spacing. This worked for me
If you can add the additional details then it will be more helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib

email = input('which email do you have?\n').lower()
while(email != 'gmail' and email != 'outlook' and email != 'yahoo'):
    email = input('Enter one of the following:\n1.Gmail\n2.Outlook\n3.Yahoo\n\n').lower()
if(email == 'gmail'):
    email = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    domain = '@gmail.com'
elif(email == 'outlook'):
    email = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
    domain = '@outlook.com'
elif(email == 'yahoo'):
    email = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
    domain = '@yahoo.com'
    
conn = smtplib.SMTP(email, 587)            # smtp.gmail.com
                                           # smtp-mail.outlook.com
                                           # smtp.mail.yahoo.com
conn.ehlo()      # Starting the connection
conn.starttls()  # Encrypting the connection

emailid = input('Enter Email address'+'('+domain+')'+'...\n')
emailid+=domain
password = input('Enter your password...\n')
while(True):
    try:
        conn.login(emailid,password)
        print('\nLogged in:)')
        break
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print('\n\nIncorrect email or password\n')
    print('Is this your email address?\n',emailid,'\n')
    yn = input().lower()
    if(yn == 'no'):
        emailid = input('Re-enter your email address\n')
    password = input('Enter password\n')

to=input('Who do you want to send the email to?\n')

subject=input('Subject : ')
text=input('Enter the message\n')

message = 'Subject: '+subject+'\n\n'+text

print('\n\n\n'+message,'\n\nsend?')
send=input()
if send=='yes':
    conn.sendmail(emailid,to,message)
    print('\nsent!')
else:
    print('ok')
    
#conn.sendmail('FROM','TO','Subject: SUBJECT\n\nMESSAGE')
```