# Yahoo smtp isn't working as expected in python 3.10.0

Tags: python, email, smtp, yahoo

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage()

email['from'] = 'PM'
email['to'] = 'someone@gmail.com'
email['subject'] = 'Test text'

email.set_content('Once upon a time ......')

with smtplib.SMTP(host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com', port = 587) as smtp:
    smtp.set_debuglevel(1)
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login('another@yahoo.com' , 'qwertuiop')
    smtp.send_message(email)
    print('Done!')
```

This is the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Desktop\untitles.py", line 17, in <module>
    smtp.login('another@yahoo.com' , 'qwertuiop')
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 432, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 405, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

And this is the error message showing

```
send: 'ehlo [192.168.*.*]\r\n'
reply: b'250-kubenode512.mail-prod1.omega.sg3.yahoo.com Hello [192.168.*.*] [49.*.*.*])\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 41697280\r\n'
reply: b'250 STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'kubenode512.mail-prod1.omega.sg3.yahoo.com Hello [192.168.*.*] [49.*.*.0])\nPIPELINING\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8BITMIME\nSIZE 41697280\nSTARTTLS'
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS'
send: 'ehlo [192.168.*.*]\r\n'
reply: b'250-kubenode512.mail-prod1.omega.sg3.yahoo.com Hello [192.168.*.*] [49.*.*.0])\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 41697280\r\n'
reply: b'250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'kubenode512.mail-prod1.omega.sg3.yahoo.com Hello [192.168.*.*] [49.*.*.*])\nPIPELINING\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8BITMIME\nSIZE 41697280\nAUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER'
send: 'AUTH PLAIN <auth data>\r\n'
reply: b'535 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.\r\n'
reply: retcode (535); Msg: b'5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.'
send: 'AUTH LOGIN <login data>\r\n'
send: 'QUIT\r\n'
```

This is the debugging log
I made sure I am not providing any wrong username or passwords

but this still doesn't work Don't know why......

Python version using 3.10.0,
Tried on 3.7+ but getting the same error,
Using sublime text + PowerShell to run the code,
The device is connected to a proper network connection. Can anyone help?

Comment: If connection closed unexpectedly you need to debug the log returned by the server, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34682107/4906348 first, then paste the error log here. HIDE ANY PERSONAL INFORMATION WHEN PASTING HERE. Thank you.

Comment: The Yahoo questions I can find are rather old. Can you tweak up the `smtplib` debug level and tell us what you see? Maybe try `ehlo` again a second time after `starttls`; some servers require that.

Comment: I'm not saying that this is definitely the issue but it's worth pointing out that there are a number of modules that are not ready for 3.10 (notably *pandas*). If you have a 3.9.x environment available it might be worth checking your code there

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @BrutusForcus smtplib and email are both in the standard library, so are 3.10-ready by definition.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Fair point but it's 3.10.0 and may not be perfect ;-)

Comment: It looks like yahoo requires OAuth2 authentication, which requires more than username/password.

Comment: Yahoo supports App Passwords to avoid OAuth2, article in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to follow the instructions from this article and successfully send mail over smtp, with an "App Password" generated via my yahoo account:

https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-send-email-with-python-705cce2bce38

Here's the code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

YAHOO_ACCOUNT='YOUR_ACCOUNT@yahoo.com'
YAHOO_PASS='YOUR_YAHOO_APP_PASSWORD'    # not your account password

def send_mail(fromAddr, toAddrs, subject, body):
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg['From'] = fromAddr
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(toAddrs)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465)
    s.ehlo()
    s.login(YAHOO_ACCOUNT, YAHOO_APP_PASSWORD)
    s.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddrs, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: It looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation,](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) or simply stick to what the OP posted.

Comment: (The Medium post suggests assembling an email message by pasting strings together, which works if you know exactly what you are doing, but is a terrible example for beginners.)